# Analysis of a mixture of carbonate salts

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, home-experiment, analytical-chemistry

We've got a mixture of carbonate salts. It's a buffer, used in fish tanks. How might we go about identifying the components and their concentrations?

I suspect it'd be hard to separate some of this. Is this correct? If so, why?

Comment: How about using the old fashion precipitation and dissolve. Like using AgCl and NH3 solution to tell some of them apart?

Comment: I was thinking particularly about sodium and potassium carbonates. I don't know how I could differentiate them via precipitation; do you?

Comment: As this currently stands, it's better as a comment. Just **one question** isn't a good answer according to SE standards.

Comment: @Jeffrey I have converted your answer to a comment, if it can be extended to fir our format, I'll be happy to undelete it.